# Consistency of restoring sqlite database from dump

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to restore a sqlite dump to a database file which is already present.

$ sqlite3 foo.db < foo.db.dump

The file foo.db is already present and some process might be reading/writing from it.
Does the above command guarantee that the resulting file will not be corrupt?
If this is not the best way to go about this problem, then please let me know a better alternative.

Thanks

Comment: sqlite will not corrupt itself at the file level (it is ACID). However, I don't believe that an implicit restore-wide transaction is created, unless such is present in the "dump" SQL itself.

Comment: Restoring from a Sqlite dump will produce a complete database. Why are you trying to execute that against an existing database, why not just create a new one and restore into that, and then replace the existing one with the one restored?

Comment: Hi Lasse, I am not sure about the replace part, will a regular rename("mv") work from temp file to actual file?